# In h2o.ai, how to load train data in java or scala?

Tags: java, scala, h2o

In my project, I will use h2o's machine learning algorithm. While I don't load the train date.
I use the folloing ways.

```
 var f = FileUtils.getFile("D:\\from_2017_2_13\\untitled2\\src\\main\\resources\\extdata\\iris_wheader.csv")
 println(11111)
 var frame = FrameUtils.parseFrame(Key.make("iris_weather.hex"),f)
 println(22222)
```

The 11111 was output, then the program will being runing, and not stopping

```
 11111
```

other way

```
 var f = FileUtils.getFile("D:\\from_2017_2_13\\untitled2\\src\\main\\resources\\extdata\\iris_wheader.csv")
 val parserSetup = H2OFrame.defaultParserSetup()
    parserSetup.setSeparator(',').setCheckHeader(ParseSetup.HAS_HEADER).setNumberColumns(5)
 val f3 = new H2OFrame(parserSetup, f)
    f3
```

the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535
 at water.DKV.get(DKV.java:202)
 at water.DKV.get(DKV.java:175)
 at water.parser.ParseSetup.createHexName(ParseSetup.java:594)
 at water.fvec.H2OFrame.<init>(H2OFrame.scala:56)
 at water.fvec.H2OFrame.<init>(H2OFrame.scala:84)
```

Answer (score 0):

To load data into Scala as H2O Frame you can do the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.h2o._
import water.support.SparkContextSupport.addFiles
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles
import java.io.File

val hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(sc)

addFiles(sc, "/Users/avkashchauhan/smalldata/iris/iris.csv")
val irisData = new H2OFrame(new File(SparkFiles.get("iris.csv")))
```

Once data is loaded you can see the data frame as below:

```
scala> irisData
res1: water.fvec.H2OFrame =
   Frame key: iris.hex
   cols: 5
   rows: 150
 chunks: 1
   size: 2454
```

Once you have ingested the data frame you can build model with it. If you are looking for a sample of using H2O library in Scala you can look for this blog for [full end to end Scala based deep learning sample in H2O](https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/multinomial-classification-example-in-scala-and-deep-learning-with-h2o/).